# How to use slide transition for images on the same form in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Pls how can i use slide transition for Images on the same Form?

I used this code, but it shows and error

```
Label lab = new Label();
 lab.setUIID("IMAGE");

  lab.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createSlideFadeTitle(true,duration.getAsInt(3000)));
```

pls how do I go about this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use slide. Slide fade is a special transition designed for forms and is used in iOS to fade the title while sliding.

The way to animate a components entrance/exit is to replace it e.g.:

```
parentContainer.replace(currentComponent, newComponent, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, true, 400);
```